# $L^1 ([0,1])$, bouned linear functional, absolute continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am studying for an Analysis prelim and was wondering if someone could perhaps either validate or invalidate my proof for the following problem:

"Let $L^1 ([0,1])$ be the space of Lebesgue integrable functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and $\varphi$ a bounded linear functional on $L^1([0,1])$.  Define the function $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = \varphi(\chi_{[0,x]})$.  Show that $g$ is absolutely continuous on the interval $[0,1]$."

Here is my proof:

Since $\varphi$ is abounded linear functional, $\exists M > 0$ such that $\forall f \in L^1([0,1])$, $|\varphi (f)| \leq M||f||$ where the norm $||\cdot||$ is defined by $||f|| = \int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|dx$.  Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and let $0 < \delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{M}$. Suppose $(a_1, b_1),\ldots , (a_N, b_N)$ is a finite collection of disjoint intervals in $[0,1]$ such that 
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{N} (b_j - a_j) < \delta.$$  Then we have that
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 1}^{N} |g(b_j)- g(a_j)| &= \sum_{j = 1}^{N}|\varphi(\chi_{[0, b_j]}) - \varphi(\chi_{[0, a_j]})| = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |\varphi(\chi_{[0, b_j]} - \chi_{[0, a_j]})|\\ &= \sum_{j = 1}^{N}|\varphi(\chi_{[a_j, b_j]})| \leq \sum_{j =1}^{N} M ||\chi_{[a_j, b_j]}|| = M \sum_{j =1}^{N}\int_{[0,1]}|\chi_{[a_j, b_j]}|dx\\ &= M \sum_{j =1}^{N}\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{[a_j, b_j]}dx = M\sum_{j =1}^{N}(b_j - a_j) < M\delta < M \frac{\varepsilon}{M} = \varepsilon.
\end{align}
Therefore $g$ is absolutely continuous on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: The proof is fine. Something you said at the start is messed up: "Since $\phi$ is a bounded linear ... for all $f\in (L^1)^*...$. No, $\phi$ is a linear functional on $L^1$.  So $\phi$ is an element of $(L^1)^*$, and that sentence should say something about all $f\in L^1$.

Comment: Ahh right thank you I knew better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varphi$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^1([0,1]),$ then there exists $g\in L^\infty([0,1])$ such that

$$\varphi (f) = \int_0^1 fg$$

for all $f\in L^1.$ Thus

$$\varphi (\chi_{[0,x]})  = \int_0^xg.$$

Since $g$ is bounded, that integral is Lipschitz, hence is absolutely continuous with room to spare.

Comment: Thanks for that input.  I haven't gotten too much into $L^p$ functions for $p > 1$ yet so I'll look back over this again when I get there.